# Question regarding the integrability of non-measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the following Lemma on p. 417 of Royden/Fitzpatrick's book on Real Analysis (Fourth Edition):

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ be measure spaces (not necessarily complete), $\mathcal{R}$ denote the semiring of measurable rectangles, $\mu\times\nu$ be the product measure and $E_{x} = \{y\in Y: (x, y)\in E\}$ for any $E\subseteq X\times Y$.

> **Lemma** Let $E\subseteq X\times Y$ be an $\mathcal{R}_{\sigma\delta}$ set for which $(\mu\times\nu)(E) < \infty$. Then for all $x$ in $X$, the $x$-section of $E$, $E_{x}$, is a $\nu$-measurable subset of $Y$, the function $x\mapsto \nu(E_{x})$ for $x\in X$ is a $\mu$-measurable function and $$(\mu\times\nu)(E) = \int_{X}\nu(E_{x})\:\text{d}\mu(x).$$

Here is a relevant portion of the proof:

*Proof:* The result can first be proved for sets in $\mathcal{R}$ and then for sets in $\mathcal{R}_{\sigma}$. Let $E\in\mathcal{R}_{\sigma \delta}$ be of finite measure. We write $E = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}E_{n}$ where $\{E_{n}\}$ is a descending sequence of sets in $\mathcal{R}_{\sigma}$ and $(\mu\times\nu)(E_{1}) < \infty$ without loss of generality. Since the lemma has been proved for $\mathcal{R}_{\sigma}$ sets, we have $$(\mu\times\nu)(E_{1}) = \int_{X}\nu((E_{1})_x)\:\text{d}\mu(x),$$ and thus $\nu((E_{1})_{x}) < \infty$ for almost all $x$. Now for each $x\in X$, $E_{x} = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}(E_{n})_{x}$ and is thus $\nu$-measurable. Furthermore, by the continuity of measure we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\nu((E_{k})_{x}) = \nu(E_{x})$ for almost all $x\in X$.

**Question:** Since $\nu((E_{k})_{x})\rightarrow\nu(E_{x})$ a.e., we can only conclude that $x\mapsto\nu(E_{x})$ is $\mu$-measurable on a subset $X_{0}$ of $X$ with $\mu(X-X_{0}) = 0$ (note that is has not been assumed that $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is complete). Since $x\mapsto\nu(E_{x})$ may not be $\mu$-measurable, we may not even be able to define its integral. In general, if $f: X\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is not measurable, but the restriction of $f$ to $X_{0}$ is measurable with $\mu(X-X_{0}) = 0$ then is it the convention to set $$\int_{X}f\:\text{d}\mu := \int_{X}\tilde{f}\:\text{d}\mu,$$ where $\tilde{f}$ is some measurable extension of $f\upharpoonright X_{0}$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm probably just missing something, but why wouldn't $\nu((E_k)_x)\to \nu(E_x)$ everywhere?

Comment: @tomasz this is because $\nu((E_{1})_{x})$ is only finite a.e. and thus we can only use the continuity of measure where it is finite.

Comment: Well, a real problem could only occur if all $(E_k)_x$ have infinite measure. But OK, I see your point.

Comment: @tomasz yes, $X_{0}$ is measurable.

Comment: I think the authors are tacitly using the convention you just mentioned. In general, in both analysis in measure theory, people tend to just disregard what happens on null sets (often completely tacitly). OTOH, I can't shake the feeling that the function should actually be measurable. But maybe not. I suppose if there is a counterexample, there is one involving the counting measure.

Comment: @tomasz I am not sure too. Thanks a lot for your help. I shall try to come up with counterexamples.